# How to fix strange behavior of attr("class") when using find().slice() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, find, slice

Can't seem to find logic in the problem I have with table header sorting arrows (for the time being only with the first one) I'm trying to control with jQuery.

On page load and upon click the two arrows in clickable **<th>** should change: 
Step 1: top one from red-colored upward caret to green-colored upward angle (from class *fas fa-caret-up* to class *fas fa-angle-up*) which is done nicely

Step 2: bottom one from green-colored downward angle to red-colored downward caret (from class *fas fa-angle-down* to *fas fa-caret-down*) but this one unfortunately becomes as messed-up as **fa-angle-up fas fa-caret-down**.

The code I'm implementing so far is:

```
 if ($(header).find("i").slice(0).attr("class") === "fas fa-caret-up") {
        alert($(header).find("i").slice(0).attr("class") + "\n" + $(header).find("i").slice(1).attr("class"));
        ($(header).find("i").slice(0).removeClass("fas fa-caret-up").addClass("fas fa-angle-up").css({ "color": "green", "font-size": "16px" }));
        alert($(header).find("i").slice(0).attr("class") + "\n" + $(header).find("i").slice(1).attr("class"));
        ($(header).find("i").slice(1).removeClass("fas fa-angle-down").addClass("fas fa-caret-down").css({ "color": "red", "font-size": "18px", "left": "0" }));
        dir = "desc";
        alert($(header).find("i").slice(0).attr("class") + "\n" + $(header).find("i").slice(1).attr("class"));
    }
```

The table and first header shown below (the rest omitted for brevity):

```
<table id="data_collector" class="table table-sm table-striped table-responsive-md btn-table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:13ch; text-align:left" class="nums" onclick="makeAllSortable(0, this)">Test No
            <div class="i-container"><i class="fas fa-caret-up" style="color:red"></i><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
            </div>
          </th>
```

...

The expected outcome should be:

Step 1: top one from red-colored upward caret to green-colored upward angle (from class *fas fa-caret-up* to class *fas fa-angle-up*)

Step 2: bottom one from green-colored downward angle to red-colored downward caret (from class *fas fa-angle-down* to *fas fa-caret-down*).

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Gshegosh/3nwqzurf/28/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out upon further reading.
The slice() allows for a second argument which is the answer to my post.